# Preserving resolution and properties of Matplotlib figure within Tkinter canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, canvas, tkinter

I've created a 3d plot via matplotlib and am having issues importing it into a tkinter canvas GUI. The screenshots below show the plot as I'd like to see it (in the standalone program) and how it's appearing within my canvas (low resolution, incorrect spacing, scales, etc).

Running the following code at the end of my standalone program gives me 1280x960, DPI 200.

```
DPI = fig.get_dpi()
bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width, height = bbox.width*fig.dpi, bbox.height*fig.dpi
```

In my tkinter canvas, I'm setting the figure (as below), and keeping all other attributes the same.

```
fig = Figure(figsize=(6.4,4.8), dpi=200)
```

**Standalone:**

[image: Standalone]

**Tkinter Canvas:**

[image: Tkinter GUI]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm a bit lost on this. Wouldn't it be better to show a [mcve] of the issue (I guess the complex plot you have is not part of the issue and can be left out) such that people can reproduce what you mean?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'll put something together, wasn't sure if there was an obvious solution